# How to set default time zone in ASP.Net Application

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Hi i have created the asp.net web application without considering the time zone. I am using directly the DateTime.Now function. Actually that returns datetime in server configured time zone format. Now i cant change entire application. so is there any way set the TimeZone of application independent of server in which it is hosted? or is there any way to set in web config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone` is used for the time zone on the computer where the code is executing.
Check these links: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.currenttimezone.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.local.aspx

Comment: I want to set my web application to (UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi format. No where in application i m using TimeZone property before i use DateTime Class. Do i need to change my application code to use TimeZone localZone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone before i use DateTime Class?

Comment: Almost same scenario is explained in another link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589014/how-to-change-time-zone-for-an-asp-net-application . I think once i need to change code in entire application to use common util class, but then any further changes only need a change in a single place. I think no option to set in web.config for my scenario.