# How to set time zone for ASP.NET MVC 5 application?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, timezone, asp.net-mvc-5

I have quite large web application, which is developed with ASP.NET MVC 5 and MsSql 2008. On my PC, I have +0700 UTC, but on my shared hosting I have other time zone.

[This code](http://dotnetfiddle.net/ug7PpK) gives me correct DateTime.

```
DateTime utcTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

string zoneID = "N. Central Asia Standard Time"; 

TimeZoneInfo myZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(zoneID);
DateTime custDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcTime, myZone);

Console.WriteLine(custDateTime.ToString());
```

Unfortunately, I have many places, where I work with date and time. I afraid, that I forget anywhere to change code.

Is there simple way to set right time zone for my web application?

P.S. All users of my application have same time zone.

Comment: add to global.asax file

Comment: This has been answered before, check out this for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293858/how-to-set-default-time-zone-in-asp-net-application

Comment: also have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560796/set-culture-in-an-asp-net-mvc-app

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the default timezone of my asp.net website in web.config file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19241815/how-to-change-the-default-timezone-of-my-asp-net-website-in-web-config-file)

Comment: You could also just take your code and wrap it into a helper method.

Comment: @Matt Johnson, yep, I develop own DateTimeUtility, which solved my problems.

Answer (score 0):

If Internationalization is important to you, you can use [this](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx).

I had very good results by understanding what was written there.

MVC Framework will know how to treat your country, language, currencies, date-times format, timestamps, etc.

Comment: ... but *not* time zones.

Comment: No mention of time zones at all in this article.